# When to merge data in a form?

Tags: forms, info-visualisation, ux-field, data-entry

I’m wondering how to make UX better in such a case

[image]
There is CRM, as a user of this CRM, I can create a customer with fields phone, email, name, address. Sometimes it’s possible when a customer with this contact information has already existed. So, as a user of CRM, I need to merge the data.

When is it the best time to make it? As soon as email or phone number is filled in and we found a coincidence? Or as a user clicks “create”?

In the first solution, I should change the title after merging “Update info” or so on, because it’s not creating even more. And it can confuse a user.
The second solution supposes to fill in an entire form and after a creating to see “merge popup”.

Comment: What's your primary search method for finding existing customers?

Comment: A user uses a global search for the entire system at first. 
E.g I enter a phone number or email in a field and if I don't find a match I create a new customer. But sometimes users don't use the search, so they can create a new customer with the same information.

Comment: Answer below is what I was going to suggest.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Where is this step located in the entire process?**

If this is a time sensitive task (someone is on the phone with the customer for example and it's best to avoid waiting times) then a solution could be to show a pop-up with a message that indicated all other customer details related to the identified duplicate (as a confirmation that this is indeed a duplicate customer). Main action there would be to cancel the creation of a new customer or update customer information (opens customer details page) as well as viewing that customer in another tab.

**2. Are coincidences frequent or is it an edge case?**

If 'coincidences' are frequent, then you could rename the main action to 'Create anyway' - indicating a deliberate choice in creating a duplicate (maybe a company shared phone or sales e-mail but different names).

In this design the fields that would require a match are already the first ones (e-mail and phone numbers) so it's a good thing that you show it pretty early in the registration process.

Example of a solution below

[image: quick sketch of a solution]

P.S.

Due to tabbing order I think the best position for the 'Cancel' action is after the primary button. Most of the users will be entering data and then tabbing away on the next field - no need to add an extra tab there.